# bash: splitting a string over several lines with conditioning

Tags: bash, if-statement

In my bash script I call a command that uses many options, defined as --option :

```
packmol-memgen --pdb "$output"/${pdb_name}_${lipid}_${distxy}A/${pdb_name}.pdb --lipids $lipid --salt --salt_c Na+ --ffprot ff14SB --fflip lipid21 --ffwat tip3p --keepligs --preoriented --distxy_fix $distxy --ratio 1 --dist_wat ${dist_wat} --parametrize --minimize
```

how could I properly rewrite this part of the code to write each option on a separate line in my bash script, in order that I could easily control the execution of the program via enabling or disabling selected options, in the following manner:

```
packmol-memgen
--pdb "$output"/${pdb_name}_${lipid}_${distxy}A/${pdb_name}.pdb
--lipids $lipid
#--salt_c Na+ # this option is desactivated
...
--parametrize
if [ "${min}" == 1 ]; then
--minimize # ! the option is enabled if boolean $min = 1
elif [ "${min}" == 0 ]; then
#--minimize # ! the option is desactivated if boolean $min = 0
fi
```

In this example I commented the last line contained the option (--minimize) which I would like to turn off by means of the boolean condition defined in the same bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the options in an array then call the command with that array providing it's arguments:

```
$ opts=( foo )
$ # opts+=( bar )
$ opts+=( etc )
$ echo "${opts[@]}"
foo etc
```

e.g. untested:

```
packmol-memgen
opts=( --pdb "$output"/${pdb_name}_${lipid}_${distxy}A/${pdb_name}.pdb )
opts+=( --lipids $lipid )
#opts+=( --salt_c Na+ ) # this option is desactivated
...
opts+=( --parametrize )
if [ "${min}" == 1 ]; then
    opts+=( --minimize ) # ! the option is enabled if boolean $min = 1
elif [ "${min}" == 0 ]; then
    :
    #opts+=( --minimize ) # ! the option is desactivated if boolean $min = 0
fi 

packmol-memgen "${opts[@]}"
```

Check your quotes by the way, see http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: Great sollution, thank you very much ED! Actually it works very well, the only minor issue the elif .. fi condition does not work when there is something commented inside it. I just added an echo message inside it, and it works OK !

Comment: You're welcome. Just use `:` if you really need an empty construct. I updated my answer to show that. Obviously you could alternatively just get rid of the whole `elif` block in this case.